# Show webpage in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office

I have an excel file with a lot of urls, which I have to look through and mark. My idea is now, to preview the urls in a tiny box when I hover over the url. However, I cannot find such functionality in excel.

Is there a functionality like this or something similar for excel to preview urls?

I really appreciate your answer!